How to get route value of action attribute in controller?
I have the action method defined like below:
[Route("example-page")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // I want to use "example-page" in here, like a query parameter.

    return View();
}

How to get action route value in controller?
I tried it like this:
var routeName = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

It returns MyAction. I couldn't find another way.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Flynetcan: The description above isn't clear enough.  What string you want to get if few Route attributes are applied to the action method? May be you want to see the currently entered url? Try to see var url = Request.Path; in the action method. Also you can analyze the System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.ToList(); routes table.

Right, the description above isn't clear enough.var url = Request.Path; and System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.ToList(); This worked for me. Thank you.

From the Microsoft Dev Blogs:

Routing is how ASP.NET MVC matches a URI to an action. MVC 5 supports
a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the name implies,
attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing
gives you more control over the URIs in your web application.

Therefore, use the HttpRequest.Path to get the virtual path of the current request and it will match the URI mapped to the corresponded controller/action that this route attribute is applied.

With ASP.NET routing, with attributes, you'd normally define the route with a 'placeholder' which then gets filled in as a method parameter. Something like this might work:
[Route("{action}")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string action)
{
    return OK(action);
}

You may need to configure a route template to make this work.

Thank you Mark, what I actually want to do is to access the value ( string in [Route("example-page")] ) before the return.

@Flynetcan Why don't you make it a constant, then?
